# Unable to retrieve TextView inside Adapter class

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, baseadapter

```
public class WishlistAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Response.UserinfoEntity> userinfo;
    private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://www.bruhnancel.xyz/" ;

    public WishlistAdapter(Context mContext, List<Response.UserinfoEntity> userinfo) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.userinfo = userinfo;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return userinfo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return userinfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wishlist_row_item, parent, false);
        Response.UserinfoEntity item = (Response.UserinfoEntity) getItem(position);
        TextView feedback_name_voted = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.feedback_name_voted);

       // TextView title = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        TextView comment_posted= (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.comment_posted);
        //TextView id = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        final TextView like_total_number= (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.like_total_number);
        ImageView pic = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.latest_promotion_pic);

        Button delete_wishlist = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete_wishlist);

        feedback_name_voted.setText("Name = " +item.getAd_title());
        comment_posted.setText(item.getCom_name());
        like_total_number.setText(item.getAd_id());
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(item.getImg_link())
                .into(pic);


        delete_wishlist.setOnClickListener(this);


        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.delete_wishlist:

                    new DeleteWishlist(like_total_number.getText().toString()).execute();

                break;



        }
    }

    private class DeleteWishlist extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        String  delete;


        public DeleteWishlist( String delete )
        {

            this.delete = delete;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //showProgressDialog("Please wait...", "Your message");

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {



            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();


            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ad_id", delete));




            try{
                HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "delete_wishlst.php");



                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
            {

                //progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Ads successfully deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);

                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    private HttpParams getHttpRequestParams(){

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, 1000 * 30);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, 1000*30);
        return httpRequestParams;
    }

    private void showProgressDialog(String title, String message)
    {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);

        progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait"); //title

        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading"); // message

        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

php

```
    $ad_id = $_POST["ad_id"];




    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "DELETE  FROM wish_list WHERE ad_id= ?");

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $ad_id);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

        mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

        mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I facing a problem in this line of code

```
new DeleteWishlist(like_total_number.getText().toString()).execute();
```

like_total_number in red color, and this is an adapter java class.

How should i fix this?because i need this value and send it to my database for deleting purpose

Comment: What do you mean "like_total_number in red color." Also, please post the error that you are getting.

Comment: the error that i get is that in my onclick, i cant retrieve "like_total_number", so in android studio "like_total_number" is red in color.

Comment: refer to Pedro Oliveira's answer, hes on the right track.

Comment: i done it and yes i can detect the like_total_number already but the button doesnt do anything..can might explain what i doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe your asyncTask delete code is wrong. Post it.

Comment: hii i edited my post, please have a look thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`like_total_number` is a variable from another scope.

You're declaring a variable in the method `getView` and trying to acess it in another method. That doesn't work like that. You need to either save it in another place or retrieve it inside the method `onClick`.

Here is a suggestion. Change your line `delete_wishlist.setOnClickListener(this);`:

```
delete_wishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DeleteWishlist(like_total_number.getText().toString()).execute();
        }
    });
}
```

This way, and since the variable `like_total_number` is final you are able to get it inside that anonymous class :)

Comment: i done it and yes i can detect the like_total_number already but the button doesnt do anything..can might explain what i doing wrong here?

Comment: That could be another issue with the task itself. This question seems to be solved. If you have another question feel free to create a new one. Before you do that perform some testings and log your actions so you can better see what's going on. Debugging ain't that hard :)

Answer (score 0):

`like_total_number` is a local variable you have declared so it will not  be accessed out of its scope.

Instead you could do something like this :

Replace

```
 delete_wishlist.setOnClickListener(this);
```

with this :

```
delete_wishlist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               new DeleteWishlist(like_total_number.getText().toString()).execute();  
            }
        });
```

Comment: i done it and yes i can detect the like_total_number already but the button doesnt do anything..can might explain what i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The answers already provided will work, but if you don't want to create an anonymous object, you could always set the tag of the button as a reference to the text view. For example:

```
final TextView like_total_number= (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.like_total_number);
Button delete_wishlist = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete_wishlist);

delete_wishlist.setTag(like_total_number);
```

then in your `onClick()` method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView like_total_number = (TextView) v.getTag();
}
```

This will pass a reference of `like_total_number` to your onClick method via the "button" that is clicked.